# Slow Response between RewritePath and Page_Load Event

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a ASP .NET 3.5 website running on IIS7 on a Windows 2008 server, that uses a HttpModule to rewrite paths, for example www.site.com/robby will get rewritten to www.site.com/item.aspx?id=123.

I have a performance problem on sign in as FireBug reports a 15-25 second "waiting for response", however is does speed up to a couple of seconds if I sign out and sign in again in the same session.  So after ruling out SSL and database work I logged the code and discovered that the time gap is between the RewritePath finishing page load event starting, there is no code in between.

So that only leaves the IIS7 pipeline or some bizarre application pool start up issue.  What I am lacking in this area is a tool that can trace what the pipeline is actually doing during this time or waiting on. Help...

Comment: Does it speed up after you remove the HttpModule?

Comment: No, as it would not run at all without my HttpModule rewriting the url's.

Answer (score 1):

There is many reasons for this delay, but without code i can't help you.

Try [ANTS Performance profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/features.htm) (14-days trial). It will show you what part of code consumes most time.

Comment: But there is no code in between context.RewritePath and the first line of the Page_Load event of the page that is being rewritten to.  Does ANTS also monitor IIS7?